# Why use a randomized quick sort, if we already get a random array?

Tags: random, runtime, code-analysis, quicksort

Why use a randomized quick sort, if we already get a random array?

If we receive a random array, and choose the last entry as the pivot every time, 
isn't that still considered random since we received a random array in which we don't even know where each entry placement they're in.

PSEUDO CODE for Regular Quicksort

```
QUICKSORT(A,p,r)
if p< r
     q = PARTITION(A,p,r)
     QUICKSORT(A,p,q-1)
     QUICKSORT(A,q+1,r)

PARTITION(A, p, r)
x = A[r]
i = p − 1
for j = p to r − 1 do
     if A[j] ≤ x then
          i = i + 1
          exchange A[i] and A[j]

exchange A[i + 1] and A[r]
return i + 1
```

PSEUDO CODE for Randomized Quicksort

```
RandPartition(A, p, r)
     i = Random(p, r)
     exchange A[r] and A[i]
     return PARTITION(A, p, r)

RandQuicksort(A, p, r)
     if p < r then
     q = RandPartition(A, p, r)
     RandQuicksort(A, p, q − 1)
     RandQuicksort(A, q + 1, r)
```

Comment: The result of a sort is always a sorted array, not a random array.  Randomization refers to the algorithm's process, not to the result.

Comment: Are you running a casino? How random does it have to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the input is known to be randomized, then the additional randomization serves no purpose. Deterministically choosing the last element as the pivot would be just as good.

The picture's quite different if the input is *not* know to to be randomized.

Comment: odds are if he's relying on quicksort for randomization, then it wasn't randomized.